# Variable function compatibility with PHP 7 and PHP5

Tags: php, php-7

I have a situation where this works in PHP5 but fatals in PHP7:

```
/* load batch processing data into variable */
$args = get_option('leads_batch_processing');
/* process batches */
self::$args['method']($args);
```

And this works in PHP7 but fatals PHP5:

```
/* load batch processing data into variable */
$args = get_option('leads_batch_processing');
/* process batches */
 self::{$args['method']}($args);
```

How can I use the variable function successfully in both PHP environments? I tried using an if condition based on PHP version but the PHP7 version's syntax fatals PHP5 so I cannot go that route.

What do I do?

Comment: [call_user_func()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)?

Comment: Could you propose it as an answer? In the case above $args is not a private or static variable. But inside $args['method'] there is a function name that exists within the calling class (self::)

Comment: The second code should work on both PHP 5 and PHP 7. Make sure you're not testing on some outdated PHP version (like 5.3).

Comment: I can't afford that context working as a WordPress plugin developer I will see PHP version from 5.3 to 7. The second version will fatal on a lower version of PHP. It doesn't like the brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign it to a regular variable, which wouldn't cause a syntax error:

```
$method = $args['method'];
$this->$method($args);
```

Or, similarly to what was suggested in the comments, use `call_user_func()`:

```
call_user_func(
    array($this, $args['method']),
    $args
);
```